# Docusign Phone Authentication with extension

Tags: docusignapi

I didn't find in Docusign documentation how to pass in the **Create Envelope** the extension of a phone number in case of Phone authorization, as in the following example:

```
"idCheckConfigurationName": "Phone Auth $",
   "requireIdLookup": "true",
   "phoneAuthentication": {
       "recipMayProvideNumber": "false",
       "senderProvidedNumbers": [
           "206-222-1111"
       ]
   }
```

And I manually created on Docusign website an envelope with Phone authentication using phone number with extension. When I call **Get Envelope Recipient** the extension information is not returned.

So I'm wondering if the extension option is not supported at all by Docusign API currently.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing below JSON, after **x** you will pass the extension:

```
"phoneAuthentication": {
      "recipMayProvideNumber": false,
      "senderProvidedNumbers": ["+11119179638x312"]
    }
```